# filter-out is not filtering file? Makefile for C

Tags: c, filter, makefile

so ive got a make file here and my project currently has a master.c and slave.c which both have main functions. therefore i just want to filter the slave.c file out of the building process. so I used fliter-out when defining the source files. but when run make the project keeps turning up with the "multiple definitions of main" error. why is this when filter-out should be hiding the slave.c file?

```mk
########################################################################
####################### Makefile Template ##############################
########################################################################

#Compiler settings - Can be customized.
CC = gcc
CXXFLAGS = -std=c11 -Wall
LDFLAGS =

# Makefile settings - Can be customized.
APPNAME = master
SUBAPPNAME = slave
EXT = .c
SRCDIR = .
OBJDIR = .

############## Do not change anything from here downwards! #############
SRC := $(filter-out slave.c, $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*$(EXT)))
OBJ := $(SRC:$(SRCDIR)/%$(EXT)=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
DEP := $(OBJ:$(OBJDIR)/%.o=%.d)
#UNIX-based OS variables & settings
RM = rm
DELOBJ = $(OBJ)
# Windows OS variables & settings
DEL = del
EXE = .exe
WDELOBJ = $(SRC:$(SRCDIR)/%$(EXT)=$(OBJDIR)\\%.o)

########################################################################
####################### Targets beginning here #########################
########################################################################

all: $(APPNAME)

# Builds the app
$(APPNAME): $(OBJ)
        $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

# Creates the dependecy rules
%.d: $(SRCDIR)/%$(EXT)
        @$(CPP) $(CFLAGS) $< -MM -MT $(@:%.d=$(OBJDIR)/%.o) >$@

# Includes all .h files
-include $(DEP)

# Building rule for .o files and its .c/.cpp in combination with all .h
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%$(EXT)
        $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

################### Cleaning rules for Unix-based OS ###################
# Cleans complete project
.PHONY: clean
clean:
        $(RM) $(DELOBJ) $(DEP) $(APPNAME)

# Cleans only all files with the extension .d
.PHONY: cleandep
cleandep:
        $(RM) $(DEP)

# Clean only all files with the extension .o
.PHONY: cleanobj
cleanobj:
        $(RM) $(DELOBJ)

# Cleans both files with .d and .o extensions
.PHONY: cleanod
cleanod:
        $(RM) $(DELOBJ) $(DEP)
```

Comment: Just guessing but the filtering is purely text based so I don't think `slave.c` and `./slave.c` will match.  You can check the value of`SRC` using `$(info SRC=[$(SRC)])` immediately after the line beginning `SRC := ` .

Comment: @G.M. yah ur right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call

```mk
SRC := $(filter-out slave.c, $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*$(EXT)))
```

is *just a string operation*, that is, `make` is unaware of the underlying file tree and tries to throw out the string `slave.c` from the liste `yoursrcdir/slave.c yoursrcdir/master.c` which obviously fails. Although you may disagree at first, this is a good thing because the semantic of filter operations on filetrees is by no means universal or easy to document or transport. Therefore `make` just looks at the presented strings and decides on the character-for-character comparison which to take and which to drop.
That said, the rewrite to

```mk
SRC := $(filter-out $(SRCDIR)/slave.c, $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*$(EXT)))
```

will do the trick in your case.
For wider reaching functionality look up the two functions `abspath` and `realpath` to get file names in a canonical format, which prevent `filter` et.al. from stumbling on differences in OS nomenclature.

Comment: You could also use `$(filter-out %/slave.c,`... to filter out slave.c in any directory